# Cloud hosting and maintain for the inhouse coded community edition?

Tags: magento2, hosting

We are wondering if Megonto offers cloud hosting and maintains only if we give the already developed community editing project. We have developed our in-house project using Magento's 2 community edition code and we have looking for a hosting provider that offers maintenance and support. So we are wondering if Magento does offer this kind of hosting or do you have any recommended hosting provider that we could get in touch with?

Thank you

Comment: AFAIK Magneto will never support your customer code, I believe you'll need to speak to an agency if you want a service like that.